# How to bypass MVC Routes as root path for static files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a following route defined

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "ViewTest",
             "Tests/{id}/{testName}/{quizId}/{quizName}",
             new { controller = "Test", action = "Start", 
                   id = "", testName = "", quizId = "", quizName = "" }
         );
```

and in javascript I am loading a xml file from database and assigning it to a variable. That xml contains some paths to `.mp3` files, which are then played on the page. All of the`.mp3` files resides in a folder `\SiteData\*.mp3` on server.

After loading my page my url look likes this:

```
http://localhost:55608/tests/18/folder-one/243/third-test-htmlexport-copy-6
```

and mp3 file wont get loaded, gets an error in Dev Console

```
GET http://localhost:55608/tests/18/folder-one/243/SiteData/003120-002.mp3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How to change/bypass exiting routes to load `.mp3` files from root like this

```
http://localhost:55608/SiteData/003120-002.mp3
```

P.S: XML file cannot be altered. The path to static resources remains the same.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.